# mean.io + videojs, how to integrate?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, mean-stack, mean.io

I'm building a web app with video support, and I would like to test some libraries. The first one is videojs, which seems a pretty nice option.

First, when doing a "$ grunt" for running the app after setting video.js and video-css.css on their respective folders (module/public/assets/js and module/public/assets/css) I get a bunch of warnings from jshint. A workaround is calling $ grunt -f, that way I could continue.

I also rtegistered those with:

```
MyModule.aggregateAsset('js','video.js');
MyModule.aggregateAsset('css','video-js.css');
```

The thing is, that Videojs uses a swf file for it's flash player. So the next question would be, how can I aggregate a swf using mean?
In videojs documentation says that I need to register the location of the swf file:

```
<script>
  videojs.options.flash.swf = "http://example.com/path/to/video-js.swf"
</script>
```

So I'm kind of lost here.

Anyone had any expierence integrating this libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Ca you post the code on a puvblic github?
I'll be happy to review and try to help if we can later on integrate as a package in mean.io